# Using an index inside a function in R that increases 1 unit after each run

Tags: r, function

I have this function and I want to run it fifty (50) times with 50 different data sets. I have to change the index in lines 4, 18, and 20 each time. (those are the only arguments that change in each run).

```
1  myfunc <- function(file){
2  library(ncdf)
3  setwd("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data")
4  AMS  <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data\\myarray.***index***.csv",header=FALSE)
5  
6  xval <- seq(-124.5,-101.5,by=1)
7  yval <- seq(31.5,48.5,by=1)
8  nx <- length(xval)
9  ny <- length(yval)
10 data_temp <- array(NA, dim=c(nx,ny))
11    for( i in 1:nx ){
12    for( j in 1:ny ) {
13        data_temp[i,j] <- (AMS[i,j])
14    }
15    }
16 dimx <- dim.def.ncdf( "lon", "degreesE", xval,unlim=FALSE)
17 dimy <- dim.def.ncdf( "lat", "degreesN", yval,unlim=FALSE)
18 dimt <- dim.def.ncdf( "time", "year", ***index*** , unlim=TRUE)
19 vari <- var.def.ncdf("precipt", "mm/d", list(dimx,dimy,dimt),999999.999 )
20 ncnew <- create.ncdf( "output.***index***.nc", var )
21 put.var.ncdf( ncnew, vari,data_temp, start=c(1,1,1), count=c(nx,ny,1) )
22 close.ncdf(ncnew)
}
```

is there any straightforward way to do that?

Comment: Do something like `lapply(vec, myfunc)`, where `myfun` takes the index as its only argument and `vec` is a vector of all the indices.

Comment: Are you familiar with `paste` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try, assuming you want the function to take the so-called index as argument,

```
myfunc <- function(file_index){
2  library(ncdf)
3  setwd("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data")
4  AMS  <- read.csv(sprintf("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data\\myarray.%d.csv", file_index),header=FALSE)
5  
6  xval <- seq(-124.5,-101.5,by=1)
7  yval <- seq(31.5,48.5,by=1)
8  nx <- length(xval)
9  ny <- length(yval)
10 data_temp <- array(NA, dim=c(nx,ny))
11    for( i in 1:nx ){
12    for( j in 1:ny ) {
13        data_temp[i,j] <- (AMS[i,j])
14    }
15    }
16 dimx <- dim.def.ncdf( "lon", "degreesE", xval,unlim=FALSE)
17 dimy <- dim.def.ncdf( "lat", "degreesN", yval,unlim=FALSE)
18 dimt <- dim.def.ncdf( "time", "year", file_index , unlim=TRUE)
19 vari <- var.def.ncdf("precipt", "mm/d", list(dimx,dimy,dimt),999999.999 )
20 ncnew <- create.ncdf(sprintf("output.%d.nc",file_index), var )
21 put.var.ncdf( ncnew, vari,data_temp, start=c(1,1,1), count=c(nx,ny,1) )
22 close.ncdf(ncnew)
}
```

and then

```
lapply(1:50, myfunc)
```

Comment: @ damienfrancois; Thanks for your good answer. Unfortunately when i use that argument"lapply" i got this error message: "error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'myfunc'not found.

Comment: I check that the finction is there using"list.files()" and it was there.i mean at the working directory.